# parse a JSON feed using GSON and get an array instead of multi params

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, gson

I'm trying to parse an ELGG resfull webservice (http://elgg.pro.tn/services/api/rest/json/?method=system.api.list) on an Android application.

I'm using the GSON library to convert the JSON feed to a JAVA object, i created all needed class for the conversion (mapping)

The issue is on the jSON Format (I can't change it):

```
{
   "status":0,
   "result":{
      "auth.gettoken":{
         "description":"This API call lets a user obtain a user authentication token which can be used for authenticating future API calls. Pass it as the parameter auth_token",
         "function":"auth_gettoken",
         "parameters":{
            "username":{
               "type":"string",
               "required":true
            },
            "password":{
               "type":"string",
               "required":true
            }
         },
         "call_method":"POST",
         "require_api_auth":false,
         "require_user_auth":false
      },
      "blog.delete_post":{
         "description":"Read a blog post",
         "function":"blog_delete_post",
         "parameters":{
            "guid":{
               "type":"string",
               "required":true
            },
            "username":{
               "type":"string",
               "required":true
            }
         },
         "call_method":"POST",
         "require_api_auth":true,
         "require_user_auth":false
      }
   }
}
```

the "result" in this format contain many child that does not have the same name (even if they have the same structure that i call "apiMethod"), the GSON try to parse this as separated object but what i want is that he parse all "result" child as a 'apiMethod' object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do  this using a `Map`, not an array, if you do not want to define all the possible fields in a `Result` object.

```
class MyResponse {

   int status; 
   public Map<String, APIMethod> result;    
}

class APIMethod {

    String description;
    String function;
    // etc
}
```

Otherwise you would need to define a `Result` object to use instead of that `Map` that had all the possible "method" types as fields, and use the `@SerializedName` annotation because of the non-legal Java names:

```
class Result {
    @SerializedName("auth.gettoken")
    APIMethod authGetToken;
    @SerializedName("blog.delete_post")
    APIMethod blogDeletePost;
    // etc
}
```

Option C if you *really* want a `List` is creating your own custom deserializer that is passed the parsed JSON and create an object that had a `List` in it instead of a `Map` or POJO.

```
class MyResponse {
    public int status;
    public List<APIMethod> methods;

    public MyResponse(int status, List<APIMethod> methods) {
        this.status = status;
        this.methods = methods;
    }
}


class MyDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<MyResponse> {

    public MyResponse deserialize(JsonElement je, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jdc) throws JsonParseException
    {
        Gson g = new Gson();
        List<APIMethod> list = new ArrayList<APIMethod>();
        JsonObject jo = je.getAsJsonObject();
        Set<Entry<String, JsonElement>> entrySet = jo.getAsJsonObject("result").entrySet();
        for (Entry<String, JsonElement> e : entrySet) {
            APIMethod m = g.fromJson(e.getValue(), APIMethod.class);
            list.add(m);
        }

        return new MyResponse(jo.getAsJsonPrimitive("status").getAsInt(), list);
    }
}
```

(Untested, but should work)

To use it you register it with:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(MyResponse.class, new MyDeserializer())
                .create();
```